# How to write czech characters from configuration file in zip file in python?

Tags: python, encoding, configuration, character-encoding, zip

I need to write some text in czech in zip file. The text in czech is stored in `config.ini` like so:

```
[txt]
content_bez = UPOZORNĚNÍ: V tomto katastrálním území není provedena digitalizace katastrální mapy.
```

As I understand, first of all I need to convert the string text into bytes to be allowed to write in zip. I got it like this:

```
content_bez_bytes = config['txt']['content_bez'].encode()
```

And then I tried to create the text file like this:

```
        with ZipFile(each_zip, 'a') as z:
            with z.open(text_path, 'w') as tx:
                tx.write(content_bez_bytes)
```

Where `each_zip` is each zip file where I want to create text file and `text_path` is path of the text file I'm creating. But all I'm getting in the outcome text file is this:

*UPOZORNÄšNĂŤ: V tomto katastrĂˇlnĂ­m ĂşzemĂ­ nenĂ­ kompletnÄ› provedena digitalizace katastrĂˇlnĂ­ mapy.*

.

But it works perfectly fine, when I write the czech text directly into the code like so:

```
content_bez = "UPOZORNĚNÍ: V tomto katastrálním území není provedena digitalizace katastrální mapy."
content_bez_bytes = content_bez.encode()
```

So I guess it have to be someting with the conversion from config file. I did insert this both in the beginning of the code and config file but no change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

.

**Does someone please knows where I'm making a mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When reading the config file, I need to use:

```
config.read(file, encoding='utf-8')
```

not just

```
config.read(file)
```